# RSS generator with caching function

Tags: php, mysql, rss, feed

Do you happen to know any good rss generator script with caching function. All the script I have found over the net so far doesn't support caching! I need the the content of rss to be generated automatically from database in a specified period of time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

First, to **add caching to the *script***, it seems like it wouldn't be too hard to put [`Zend_Feed`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.html) and [`Zend_Cache`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html) together - or just wrap your current generation script with `Zend_Cache`.

Just setup the cache with your lifetime:

```
$frontendOptions = array(
  'lifetime' => 7200, // cache lifetime of 2 hours
  'automatic_serialization' => true
);
```

Then check if the cache is still valid:

```
if(!$feed = $cache->load('myfeed')) {
  //generate feed
  $cache->save($feed, 'myfeed');
}

//output $feed
```

I don't know how you form your RSS, but you can [import an array structure to `Zend_Feed`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.importing.html#zend.feed.importing.custom.importarray):

```
$rssFeedFromArray = Zend_Feed::importArray($array, 'rss');
```

Of course the **best way** may be to just **use your current feed generator and save the output to a file**. Use that file as the RSS feed, then use cron/web hooks/queue/whatever to generate the static file. That would be simpler, and use less resources, than having the generation script do the caching.

```
//feedGen.php
//may require some output buffering if the feed generator outputs directly
$output = $myFeedGenerator->output();
file_put_contents('feed.rss', $output);
```

Now the feed link is `/feed.rss`, and you just run `feedGen.php` whenever it needs to be refreshed. Serving the static file (not even parsed by php) means less for your server to do.