# RSS to HTML converter class for PHP

Tags: php, rss

Does anyone know a class or script that can extract the contents from an RSS file (a URL) and convert it to HTML for displaying. Ideally it should be able to take care of a couple of chores such as caching.

## EDIT

Seems like I also need a class that does things the other way round i.e. generates RSS from data... any array may be or from database data. Again, it should be able to perform caching and not query the database every time a feed is requested.

Comment: at least related if not duplicate: [RSS generator with caching function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538000/rss-generator-with-caching-function). Apart from that, any XML extension of PHP will do. Just have to add caching then.

Comment: Who downvoted this question and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) is very handy for parsing RSS feeds.  It has a nice sample for using it and displaying the feed.

Comment: How quickly one would be able to display an external feed using this class?

Comment: And most importantly, from where do I download SimplePie?

Comment: I cannot figure out whats the difference between https://github.com/cweiske/simplepie/downloads and https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie/downloads. Anyway I got it work in less than 15 minutes of coding.